# Publish feature in PDF like in office 2010 (wishful thinking)

Tags: pdf

Just as user has a publish feature option available for MS office . is there some kind of publish directly to sharepoint 2010 available for  PDF  documents or do the users have to go the usual route  to upload documents

Comment: Are you looking to have a "Publish to SharePoint..." menu/button in Adobe Acrobat?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Word Automation Services allows you to do this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff181518.aspx

Relevant code from that article:

```
    ConversionJobSettings jobSettings;
    ConversionJob pdfConversion;
    string wordFile;
    string pdfFile;

    // Initialize the conversion settings.
    jobSettings = new ConversionJobSettings();
    jobSettings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;

    // Create the conversion job using the settings.
    pdfConversion = 
      new ConversionJob("Word Automation Services", jobSettings);

    // Set the credentials to use when running the conversion job.
    pdfConversion.UserToken = properties.Web.CurrentUser.UserToken;

    // Set the file names to use for the source Word document
    // and the destination PDF document.
    wordFile = properties.WebUrl + "/" + properties.ListItem.Url;
    if (properties.ListItem.Name.Contains(".docx"))
    {
      pdfFile = wordFile.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
    }
    else
    {
      pdfFile = wordFile.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
    }

    // Add the file conversion to the conversion job.
    pdfConversion.AddFile(wordFile, pdfFile);

    // Add the conversion job to the Word Automation Services 
    // conversion job queue. The conversion does not occur
    // immediately but is processed during the next run of
    // the document conversion job.
    pdfConversion.Start();
```

Comment: That is just for MS-Word.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a third party component such as [this one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx).

Note that I have worked on this product so I am obviously biased :-)